# ansible replace regex with variable

Tags: ansible

I am trying to replace `localhost` in the string

`$amp_conf['AMPDBHOST'] = 'localhost';`

with the content of the variable `{{ asterisk_db_host }}`, which is `172.17.0.3`.

Even though

```
- replace:
    dest: /usr/src/freepbx/installlib/installcommand.class.php
    regexp: '(\$amp_conf\[.AMPDBHOST.\] = .)localhost(.;)'
    replace: '\1\2'
```

perfectly results in

`$amp_conf['AMPDBHOST'] = 'localhost';`

```
- replace:
    dest: /usr/src/freepbx/installlib/installcommand.class.php
    regexp: '(\$amp_conf\[.AMPDBHOST.\] = .)localhost(.;)'
    replace: '\1{{ asterisk_db_host }}\2'
```

as well as

```
- replace:
    dest: /usr/src/freepbx/installlib/installcommand.class.php
    regexp: '(\$amp_conf\[.AMPDBHOST.\] = .)localhost(.;)'
    replace: '\1{{ asterisk_db_host|regex_escape() }}\2'
```

replace the string with `O2.17.0.2';` or `O2\.17\.0\.2';`.

What am I doing wrong here? How can I properly do this replacement?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your replacement string looks like this:

```
'\1{{ asterisk_db_host }}\2'
```

After Jinja templating, this is what actually gets used as the replacement string in the regex module:

```
'\1172.17.0.3\2'
```

Look at that first term.  It's no longer `\1`, it's now `\1172`, which is clearly erroneous.  One way of solving this is to make the quotes around the value part of your replacement (because when you do this, there will be a non-digit character -- the quote -- separating your backreference from the value of the template expansion).  Here's one option:

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    asterisk_db_host: "172.17.0.3"
  tasks:
    - replace:
        dest: ./cfgfile
        regexp: >-
          (\$amp_conf\[.AMPDBHOST.\] = )'localhost'(;)
        replace: >-
          \1'{{ asterisk_db_host }}'\2
```

This uses YAML block quoting (`>-`) so that we don't need to worry about escaping quotes in our expressions, and it seems to do the right thing in my simple tests.

Comment: Is using `>-` any different to using `>`? What is the difference to `|`?

Comment: Using `>` by itself will result in the value ending with a newline, which may or may not be significant.  Using `>-` avoids this terminal newline.  `|` is a literal block (it preserves newlines), while `>` wraps text to a single line.  For details, read the [Scalars](http://www.yaml.org/spec/current.html#id2503232) portion of the YAML spec.

Comment: if I am not mistaken this adds quotes which is fine as long as you want to use them. But how can it work if you could not use it? For example HEAP_SIZE=256 and I want to change it with HEAP_SIZE=128 hmm? obviously one way is to write HEAP_SIZE= itself manually to the replacement string but what if I wanted to re-use match?

Answer (score 0):

Another solution would be to use named groups:

```
  replace:
    dest: /usr/src/freepbx/installlib/installcommand.class.php
    regexp: '(?P<firstpart>\$amp_conf\[.AMPDBHOST.\] = .)localhost(.;)'
    replace: '\g<firstpart>{{ asterisk_db_host }}\2'
```

Inspired by http://www.handverdrahtet.org/2016/01/ansible-using-numbered-backreference.html